# Is there a way to toggle options in a select menu with a button, using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

Is there an onclick javascript function which would allow me to toggle between two options in a select input, using a button?

```
<html>

<head>

</head>

<body>

<button id="flavorBtn" class="flavorBtn">Toggle Flavors</button><br><br>

<select name="flavor" id="selectField">
    <option value="Vanilla">Vanilla</option>
    <option Value="Chocolate">Chocolate</option>
</select>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const select = document.querySelector('#selectField')
document.querySelector('#flavorBtn').addEventListener('click', () => {
  select.selectedIndex = (select.selectedIndex + 1) % select.options.length
})
```

```html
<button id="flavorBtn" class="flavorBtn">Toggle Flavors</button><br><br>

<select name="flavor" id="selectField">
    <option value="Vanilla">Vanilla</option>
    <option Value="Chocolate">Chocolate</option>
</select>
```